# Tracing bitcoin wallet with the address

Tags: wallet

I once created a bitcoin account and obtained an address. When i needed to transfer some bitcoin, i didn't check the address hoping it was active. After the transfer, I tried opening it but it did not. I thereafter created another account. What happens to my transfer?
Secondly, how do I use the address to locate the bitcoin wallet so my money wont be lost?
Thanks.

Comment: There's no concept of an "active" address or a Bitcoin account. If you have an account with a company, they control your bitcoin address (they hold the private keys), and you'd have to contact them.

Answer (score 1):

> **I once created a bitcoin account**

This implies you created an account with an online business through a website. Perhaps they managed your money for you in their wallet. This is arguably the most insecure way for you to hold Bitcoin.

> **and obtained an address**

You don't mention a private-key. If you don't have sole control of your private-key from its creation until now, then you don't really own any bitcoin yourself.

> **What happens to my transfer?**

If you have an account (or two) with some online business, you have to contact them to find out what happened to any money you gave them.

If so, this isn't really a question about Bitcoin itself - which was designed to work without the need for any online business to hold your Bitcoins for you.

Bitcoin transactions cannot be reversed or cancelled. The Bitcoins are owned by anyone who knows the private-key for the address you sent Bitcoins to.

> **how do I use the address to locate the bitcoin wallet so my money wont be lost?**

You can't use an address to find a wallet.

You can look inside wallets to see which addresses they contain. If a wallet contains an address that matches the address you originally obtained - then you have found one of possibly several wallets that can spend the Bitcoins associated with that address.

20-30% of all Bitcoins are lost forever and can never be spent by anyone at all.